# How do I wrap SVG <g> elements inside <div>?

Tags: html, reactjs, svg

I am trying to understand why surrounding SVG elements such as - `<g>`, `<rect>`, `<circle>` with `<div>` does not work.

I am creating an interactive visualization. In this visualization, I have `<circle>` wrapped in `<g>`. When using `react-contextmenu` npm to add context menu, it adds `<div>` elements around `<g>` and resulting in no output.

To reproduce the issue, I used a MDN example. Following code shows 2 circles as expected -

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <!-- Using g to inherit presentation attributes -->
    <g fill="white" stroke="green" stroke-width="5">
        <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="25" />
        <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="25" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/phfj3a2u/

If I surround `<g>` with `<div>`, I see a blank screen.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <div>
        <g fill="white" stroke="green" stroke-width="5">
            <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="25" />
            <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="25" />
        </g>
    </div>
</svg>
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/5m2at4bw/

**EDIT : Adding an example to illustrate the need of `<div>`**

```
//index.js
import React          from 'react';
import ReactDOM       from 'react-dom';
import App            from './components/App.js';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```
//components/App.js
import React from 'react';
import {
  ContextMenu,
  MenuItem,
  ContextMenuTrigger } from 'react-contextmenu';

export default class App extends React.PureComponent {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleClick(e, data) {
    console.log(data.circleId);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <g fill="white" stroke="green" strokeWidth="5">
            <ContextMenuTrigger id = "firstCircle">
              <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="5" />
            </ContextMenuTrigger>

            <ContextMenu id = "firstCircle">
              <MenuItem data = {{circleId : 1 }} onClick = {this.handleClick}>
                ContextMenu Item 1
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem data = {{circleId : 1 }} onClick = {this.handleClick}>
                ContextMenu Item 2
              </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>

            <ContextMenuTrigger id = "secondCircle">
              <circle cx="10" cy="30" r="5" />
            </ContextMenuTrigger>

            <ContextMenu id = "secondCircle">
              <MenuItem data = {{circleId : 2 }} onClick = {this.handleClick}>
                ContextMenu Item 1
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem data = {{circleId : 2 }} onClick = {this.handleClick}>
                ContextMenu Item 2
              </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

When react builds the app, `<svg>` element looks like as -

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <g fill="white" stroke="green" stroke-width="5">
  <div class="react-contextmenu-wrapper">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="5">
    </circle>
  </div>

  <nav role="menu" tabindex="-1" class="react-contextmenu" style="position: fixed; opacity: 0; pointer-events: none;">
    <div class="react-contextmenu-item" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false">ContextMenu Item 1</div>
    <div class="react-contextmenu-item" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false">ContextMenu Item 2</div>
  </nav>

  <div class="react-contextmenu-wrapper">
    <circle cx="10" cy="30" r="5">
    </circle>
  </div>
  <nav role="menu" tabindex="-1" class="react-contextmenu" style="position: fixed; opacity: 0; pointer-events: none;">
    <div class="react-contextmenu-item" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false">ContextMenu Item 1</div>
    <div class="react-contextmenu-item" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false">ContextMenu Item 2</div>
  </nav>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Please notice the `<div>` wrapping around `<circle>`. This causes blank screen. Now, I know why that's happening. I am looking for suggestions on how to fix this.

Comment: Probably want to take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject

Comment: @WaldirBolanos I tried it. But, it does not work. JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/phfj3a2u/1/

Comment: In the foreignObject example the `<div>` is inside that context, but there is nothing wrapping the circles, so they are subject to the xhtml rules that are attached to the div element and one is wrapped in the other and neither is in an svg context. I suspect you'll have more luck with a different approach to adding a context menu.

Comment: All SVG elements parents must be other SVG elements except for <svg> elements. What are you trying to achieve with the <div>?

Comment: Or to put it more directly, `<div>` is **not** a valid SVG element.  You can not use it inside an `<svg>`.  The loose equivalent of a `<div>` in an SVG is the `<g>` element.  However their behaviour is definitely not the same.

Comment: @RobertLongson I have added a specific example in which I don't have control over `<div>` usage.